# Best way to create or add number on object property

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, properties, numbers

When we have an object with a numeric property that works as an accumulation. What's the best way to deal the "accumulate/create" case in ES6 javascript? The simplest way would be:

```
if (obj.foo)) {
    obj.foo += value;
}
else {
    obj.foo = value;
}
```

or

```
obj.foo = obj.foo ? obj.foo + value : value;
```

ideas to improve this? thanks!

Comment: what about initializing the `foo` like `var obj = {foo:0}` always, then you don't need to worry about if `foo` exists?

Comment: @Sphinx That's good advice. The question would be more appropriate if the property were dynamic, so you can't pre-create all the properties.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that's the case, in my case, it is a dynamic key for this new property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the current value or initialize with `0` then add.

```
obj.foo = (obj.foo || 0) + value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `undefined + number => NaN` and boolean coercion of NaN is false `!!NaN === false` then:

`obj.foo + 1` can only be `NaN` or a `number` so you can simply do:

```js
obj.foo = obj.foo + value || value; // if obj.foo + 1 is NaN, then the result is 1.
```

**Despite the fact that this looks simple, bear in mind that due to implicit coercion 0 and NaN are both false: `!!0 === !!NaN` so this is only recommended for positive numbers other than 0.**

In that case if `obj.foo + value === 0` the function above will be 1 instead of 0.